# Opening input when writing #Q# in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea

I have textarea. Now, I want to do that once you write "#q + number#" ( e.g. #q1# ), it will create new input field.
For example if you write: "Hello my name is #q1# and my favorite food is #q2#". It will open two input fields.

And when you delete one of those #q + number#, it will delete the same field that was intended to the #q#

For example: if you write "Hello my name is #q1# and my favorite food is #q2#, and the input fields look like that:

```
<input type="text" q="1" />
<input type="text" q="2" />
```

and next that I delete the #q1# it supposed to look like that:

and don't delete the value of q="2" input.

How can I do that in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: do some brain storming and come up with some js code, than you can be helped to finish up the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NgxvP/1/

Comment: You are genius! thanks. But, I found error: when I delete #q1# and add him again, he appended in the end.

Comment: Shouldn't it append if it's not present yet?

Comment: But not to the end of the list, it came to situation that input q="2" is the first input and q="2" is the last one.

Comment: By the way, how can I make two inputs each #q + number#?

Comment: Well it doesn't make much sence to have several fields with same name/id, but if you really want, line `if (!$('#' + id, fieldsCont).length) {` checks if the field already exists.

Comment: I wanna to make two inputs, i tried to do this:      var field = $('<input>', {
      id: id,
      type: 'text',
      name: id
     });
     
     var field2 = $('<input>', {
      id: id,
      type: 'text',
      name: id
     });
     
     field.appendTo(fieldsCont).wrap('<div id="field-wrap-' + id + '" class="field-wrap" />');
     
     $("#field-wrap-" + id).append("<input type='' />");

Answer (score 0):

Here you have something to start playing with

```
<html>

<head>

    <style>

        #inputField {   position:relative;
                        width: 200px;
                        height: 200px;
                        background-color: #cda;
                    }

    </style>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // in_array function provided by phpjs.org
        function in_array (needle, haystack, argStrict)
        {
            var key = '',
                strict = !! argStrict;

            if (strict)
            {
                for (key in haystack)
                {
                    if (haystack[key] === needle)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (key in haystack)
                {
                    if (haystack[key] == needle)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        var addedFields = new Array();
        function checkFields(input, charCode)
        {
            var text = (charCode) ? input.value + String.fromCharCode(charCode) : input.value;

            var pattern = /#q[0-9]#/g;
            var matches = text.match(pattern);
            if (!matches) { matches = new Array(); }


            if (addedFields.length>0 && addedFields.length != matches.length)
            {
                for (var index in addedFields)
                {
                    if (!in_array('#q'+ index +'#', matches))
                    {
                        $('#q'+index).remove();
                        delete addedFields[index];
                    }
                }
            }

            if (matches)
            {
                for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++)
                {
                    var code = matches[i];
                    var index = code.match(/[0-9]/)[0];
                    if ( $('#q'+index).length == 0 )
                    {
                        addFields(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    function addFields(i)
    {
        addedFields[i] = true;
        var fields = '';
        for (var index in addedFields)
        {
            fields += '<input type="text" q="'+ index +'" id="q'+ index +'" />';
        }
        $('#inputField').html(fields);
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="formID">
    <form>
        <textarea onkeypress="checkFields(this, event.charCode); return true;" onkeyup="checkFields(this); return true;"></textarea>
        <div id="inputField"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDITED:** to avoid appending unordered input text fields, but showing them always ordered by their index, as commented in `dfsq` answer

I created a jsfiddle for your convenience http://jsfiddle.net/2HA5s/